# How do I add a newline to command output in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, newline

I run the following code using PowerShell to get a list of add/remove programs from the registry:

```
Get-ChildItem -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { Write-Output $_.GetValue("DisplayName") } `
    | Out-File addrem.txt
```

I want the list to be separated by newlines per each program. I've tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { Write-Output $_.GetValue("DisplayName") `n } `
    | out-file test.txt

Get-ChildItem -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall `
    | ForEach-Object {$_.GetValue("DisplayName") } `
    | Write-Host -Separator `n

Get-ChildItem -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { $_.GetValue("DisplayName") } `
    | foreach($_) { echo $_ `n }
```

But all result in weird formatting when output to the console, and with three square characters after each line when output to a file. I tried `Format-List`, `Format-Table`, and `Format-Wide` with no luck. Originally, I thought something like this would work:

```
Get-ChildItem -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { "$_.GetValue("DisplayName") `n" }
```

But that just gave me an error.

Comment: Get-ChildItem -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall `
    | ForEach-Object -Process { "$($_.GetValue("DisplayName")) `n" }

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Or, just set the [output field separator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6#ofs) (OFS) to double newlines, and then make sure you get a string when you send it to file:

```
$OFS = "`r`n`r`n"
"$( gci -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | 
    ForEach-Object -Process { write-output $_.GetValue('DisplayName') } )" | 
 out-file addrem.txt
```

Beware to use the <kbd>`</kbd> and not the <kbd>'</kbd>. On my keyboard (US-English Qwerty layout) it's located left of the <kbd>1</kbd>.
(Moved here from the comments - Thanks Koen Zomers)

Comment: This actually worked. But, if any other values are added, i.e. $_.GetValue('InstallDate'), then it messes up. It fulfills the original question though so thanks for the help.

Comment: I added an alternate answer below which I think is probably better :)

Answer (score 100):

Give this a try:

```
PS> $nl = [Environment]::NewLine
PS> gci hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | 
        ForEach { $_.GetValue("DisplayName") } | Where {$_} | Sort |
        Foreach {"$_$nl"} | Out-File addrem.txt -Enc ascii
```

It yields the following text in my addrem.txt file:

```
Adobe AIR

Adobe Flash Player 10 ActiveX

...
```

Note: on my system, GetValue("DisplayName") returns null for some entries, so I filter those out. BTW, you were close with this:

```
ForEach-Object -Process { "$_.GetValue("DisplayName") `n" }
```

Except that within a string, if you need to access a property of a variable, that is, "evaluate an expression", then you need to use subexpression syntax like so:

```
Foreach-Object -Process { "$($_.GetValue('DisplayName'))`r`n" }
```

Essentially within a double quoted string PowerShell will expand variables like `$_`, but it won't evaluate expressions *unless* you put the expression within a subexpression using this syntax:

```
$(`<Multiple statements can go in here`>).
```

Comment: I tried both of the suggestions above and the formatting still is not 100%. Each newline shows up as a little square (unicode maybe?) in Notepad. In Wordpad everything seems fine, but Word complains about encoding. 

Using Foreach { "$($_.GetValue('DisplayName'))`n" } still outputs the wrong format in any file.

Comment: The default output for Powershell is Unicode.  I'll modify the example to show how to save in ascii format.

Comment: I've tried every encoding option for out-file and none of them gave me the right results. I checked the environment variable $OutputEncoding and everything came up US-ASCII. I think I am going to try a different approach, maybe in python.

Answer (score 7):

I think you had the correct idea with your last example. You only got an error because you were trying to put quotes inside an already quoted string. This will fix it:

```
gci -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object -Process { write-output ($_.GetValue("DisplayName") + "`n") }
```

Edit: Keith's $() operator actually creates a better syntax (I always forget about this one). You can also escape quotes inside quotes as so:

```
gci -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall | ForEach-Object -Process { write-output "$($_.GetValue(`"DisplayName`"))`n" }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. This ought to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Ultimately, what you're trying to do with the EXTRA blank lines between each one is a little confusing :)

I think what you really want to do is use [Get-ItemProperty](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849851.aspx). You'll get errors when values are missing, but you can suppress them with `-ErrorAction 0` or just leave them as reminders. Because the Registry provider returns extra properties, you'll want to stick in a [Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx) that uses the same properties as the Get-Properties.

Then if you want each property on a line with a blank line between, use [Format-List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849957.aspx) (otherwise, use [Format-Table](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849892.aspx) to get one per line).

```
gci -path hklm:\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall |
gp -Name DisplayName, InstallDate | 
select DisplayName, InstallDate | 
fl | out-file addrem.txt
```

Comment: Yes! I should have done it this way from the beginning, instead of messing around with new lines. Thanks for the help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

The option that I tend to use, mostly because it's simple and I don't have to think, is using [Write-Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) as below. Write-Output will put an EOL marker in the string for you and you can simply output the finished string.

```
Write-Output $stringThatNeedsEOLMarker | Out-File -FilePath PathToFile -Append
```

Alternatively, you could also just build the entire string using Write-Output and then push the finished string into [Out-File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849882.aspx).